# CSS Grid Container shrinks inside a Flex container (Storybook reproduction)

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, css-grid

Does anyone have insight as to why this code does what it does?  I have a grid container with 4 elements inside that should display them horizontally with a 15px gap between them.  Not sure why, but Storybook has centering code that uses a flex container to vertically center the contents, but in doing so it shrinks my grid container down to an 8px width.  Removing `display: flex` resolves the issue, but breaks the centering display.  What CSS do I need to add to this component to ensure that it maintains sufficient width to display the numbers horizontally without hard-coding a width value?

```
<div id="sb-addon-centered-wrapper">
  <div id="sb-addon-centered-inner">
    <div id="grid">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#sb-addon-centered-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
#sb-addon-centered-inner {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#grid { 
 display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, max-content));
}
```

https://codepen.io/eriklharper/pen/oNjpgVj?editors=1100

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid items are squeezed (and wrap) because `flex-grow: 1` on the child of `.sb-addon-centered-inner` isn't doing anything.

```
<div id="sb-addon-centered-wrapper">
  <div id="sb-addon-centered-inner">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;"> <------ THIS
      <div id="grid">
           …
```

`.sb-addon-centered-inner` doesn't have `display: flex` or `inline-flex` applied, so it's children won't recognize flex properties.

Add `flex-grow: 1` to `.sb-addon-centered-inner` instead, which is a flex item.

Then, center the content with `justify-content: center` on the grid container.

```
#sb-addon-centered-inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#grid { 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
#sb-addon-centered-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

#sb-addon-centered-inner {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1; /* new */
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, max-content));
  /* min-width: 18px; */
  justify-content: center; /* new */
}

#grid div {
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sb-addon-centered-wrapper">
  <div id="sb-addon-centered-inner">
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
      <div id="grid">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael!  I see what is going on now thanks to your answer.  I also noticed that the extra div with the inline style was something I added for debugging that I forgot to remove before I asked the question.  I've updated the codepen to reflect that.  While your solution as written works, and it is likely I'll create an official issue on Storybook's github for that if necessary, I also found that if I set a `max-width: 100vw` on my `#grid` that also fixes it too.